# Python: Json to object, ignore certain characters

Tags: python, json, odata, namedtuple

Currently I am converting a json to a Python object using the namedtuple class. This way I can easily select data for e.g. `print(json.some_json_variable)`. However, my Json contains the following key: `"@odata.context"` and this ofcourse, cannot be used as a variable name because it contains a `"@"` and a `"."`.

At the moment I am using the `json.load(json)` function to load the json. Then I rename the `"@odata.context"` key, to `"odataContext"` so that it no longer contains a `"@"` and a "`.`". Next, I convert the json to a string using `json.dumps(json)` and after that, I convert it to an object using the `json.loads(json)` function. As you can understand, this method is not really efficient.

```py
def load_json(input_json):
    with open(input_json, 'r') as l_json:
        data = json.load(l_json)
        data["odataContext"] = data.pop("@odata.context")
        data = json.dumps(data)
        data = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('data', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

Is there any way this can be done more efficiently? I think that using up to 2 functions can be easily achievable, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the unwanted characters in the `object_hook=` parameter lambda:

```
json_data = '''{
    "@odata.context": 1,
    "variable": "Hello"
}'''

import json
from collections import namedtuple

def load_json(input_json):
    data = json.loads(input_json, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('data', (k.replace('@', '').replace('.', '_') for k in d.keys()) )(*d.values()))
    return data

data = load_json(json_data)
print(data.odata_context)
print(data.variable)
```

Prints:

```
1
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be to replace `"@odata.context"` with `"odataContext"` before loading it into JSON. Try something like:

```
def load_json(input_json):
    with open(input_json, 'r') as l_json:
        data = l_json.read().replace("@odata.context", "odataContext")
        data = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('data', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```